# How to form an array of nested arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Having some trouble using 2 arrays to form a new array of subarrays depending on whether the phones match up with the sims.
I want to organise:

```
let phones = ["phone1", "phone2", "phone3"]

let sims = [ 'phone1sim1', 'phone1sim2', 'phone2sim1', 'phone2sim2', 'phone1sim3', 'phone3sim1' ]
```

into an array of subarrays like so:

```
let orgPhones = [

  ["phone1", ["phone1sim1", "phone1sim2"]],
  ["phone2", ["phone2sim1", "phone2sim2"]],
  ["phone3", ["phone3sim1"]]

]
```

any suggestions appreciated!!

Comment: `Having some trouble using`  please post the code also, in which you're having trouble

Comment: Why are you using that format and not `{"phone1": ["phone1sim1", "phone1sim2"],"phone2": ["phone2sim1", "phone2sim2"], "phone3": ["phone3sim1"]}`

Answer (score 2):

To return exactly what you require, you can utilise the `Array.protoype` methods; [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like so:

```
const organised = phones.map((phone)=> [phone, sims.filter(sim => sim.indexOf(phone)!== -1)]);
```

However, I would strongly encourage you to utilise a JavaScript object instead of an array, like so:

```
{
    phone1: ['phone1sim1', 'phone1sim2', 'phone1sim3']
    phone2: ['phone2sim1', 'phone2sim2']
    // etc...
}
```

Based on the anticipated result outlined above, I would use something along the lines of the following:

```
const phones = ['phone1', 'phone2', 'phone3'];
const sims = ['phone1sim1', 'phone1sim2', 'phone2sim1', 'phone2sim2', 'phone1sim3', 'phone3sim1'];

const organised = {};

phones.map((phone)=> organised[phone] = sims.filter(sim => sim.indexOf(phone)!== -1));
```

Comment: awesome thank you. i just wanted arrays initially then will be converting them into a js object

Answer (score 2):

You can use Map like this:

```js
let phones = ["phone1", "phone2", "phone3"]

let sims = [ 'phone1sim1', 'phone1sim2', 'phone2sim1', 'phone2sim2', 'phone1sim3', 'phone3sim1' ]

let map = phones.reduce((map,phone)=>{
  return map.set(phone,sims.filter(sim=>sim.startsWith(phone)))
},new Map())

console.log(...map)
```

Comment: This is the best answer - although, I would still strongly suggest using an `object` instead of an `array`. +1

Comment: @Ben We have a `Map` that's more or less similar to `object`. We can use `Map.get(key)`  to retrieve value array. 2D arrays can easily be converted to maps of keys/values and vice versa.

Comment: Oh yes!!!! I was focusing on the `reduce` and `startsWith` bits. This is a great answer!

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate over `phones` array, and search for the related sim in `sims` array

```js
let phones = ["phone1", "phone2", "phone3"]

let sims = ['phone1sim1', 'phone1sim2', 'phone2sim1', 'phone2sim2', 'phone1sim3', 'phone3sim1']

const res = phones.map((phone) => [phone, sims.filter(sim => sim.indexOf(phone) !== -1)])
console.log(res);
```